# Communicating with a Raspberry Pi that is underwater ?

Tags: sensor

Is there a way, that I can communicate with a Raspberry Pi, that is underwater. The depth of the Raspberry Pi will be about 20 meters or less. I was thinking of using Bluetooth, or 433Hz RF Transmitter or other such sensors, but I am not too sure, if they will work. My goal is to have a transmitter and receiver with the Raspberry Pi, and I will have a controller that has transmitter and receiver as well, but I am not sure what transmitters and receivers, or if any, will work on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: There is a reason that submarines come to the surface to communicate.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_with_submarines

Comment: I would go with the [ELF option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_with_submarines#Extremely_low_frequency). >_<

Comment: WiFi - Bluetooth won't work that far, but lower frequency has a greater chance

Comment: Yes, I see that i need low frequency transmitters. Do you guys know any transmitters which are low frequency, around 3 to 300 Hertz ?  And also receivers that are able to receive this frequency, that are able to work with the RPi ?

Comment: There are lot of circuits on google but what do you actually want to transmit and receive, since as the frequency gets lower the amount of transferrable data in a period also gets lower, so low frequency might not be a solution for your project

Comment: I want to transmit basic commands, such as turn GPIO's to high or low, take a picture with the pi Camera or other such commands.

Comment: Sorry, I was being sarcastic when I said I would go with the ELF / low frequency option -- if you read the wikipedia bit, you will recognize that is completely infeasible.  There obviously are RC submarines, although note that RC is a one-way, very low bitrate, relationship.   In any case, all of this doesn't have much to do with the pi, and this is probably not the best place to be asking about it..

Comment: ..First you need to find out what is generally possible WRT ranges, bitrates, and types of equipment. Once you have a handle on that, you can inquire whether it is possible with a pi. I suggest you begin by doing a bit of searching/reading, then asking on our larger sibling site, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), and minimize or leave out references to the pi. If your goal is a submarine, it may be that the pi is inappropriate, but to know that you must first get a grip on what is necessary for such communication.  For that reason, I am closing this as off-topic.

Comment: E.g.: The question of how feasible bluetooth is underwater has nothing to do with the pi.  Even though you can attach a bluetooth dongle to a pi, the pi does not determine how that adapter in particular or bluetooth generally works.

Comment: Relevant, from the Amateur Radio StackExchange: http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/shallow-underwater-wireless-sensor-network

Comment: @WineSoaked That at least confirms some of the challenges (particularly since it is < 2m depth and the OP wants ~20m)...an interesting thing to note is the distinction between salt and fresh water in terms of conductivity, and thus radio-problematical-ity.

Comment: You will have to use underwater acoustic sensors and they're relatively very costly as compared to 2.4 Ghz or other methods that are normally used in open space communications. It would be worth to note that bit rate in these type of communication is relatively very slow. I remember one of my professor working in this area of research and he used to achieve like 7 bytes / second, it is mainly because it relies on speed of sound in water. Hope it helps.

Comment: A receiver - transmitter pair that my professor used (that was about 2 years ago) costed about 1000 to 1200 USD if I remember it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good General rule of thumb, is if it will work on an Arduino Due or Zero (those are the 3.3 volt Arduinos I know of), it will work with a Pi.

Another solution is, if the Pi is tethered for power or something else, is to run a physical cable carrying whatever you need transmitted.

Comment: Ok, Thank You. I wanted the communication to be wireless without any physical cables. Is there transmitters and receivers that can work for this purpose, and that can be wired on the RPi, and programmed ?

Comment: Satisfy my curiosity, how is the Pi powered?

Comment: Batteries. 12V , Lithium